# How to toggle views filter when user click on tab?

Tags: views, 6, ajax, javascript, nodes

i got 2 tabs and i want to achive this goal: once user click on tab 1 for example, its shows him a filters for tab1, if he clicks on other tab, its toggles the form to other "sory by" forms elements related to tab2, im using drupal 6 and jquery
attached image for demo: http://www.media396.com/tmp/tabsexampleugly.png

Answer (score 2):

You can define two displays in the View which both pull from the "Default" view and use the Tab option for the menu type. Then, override the exposed filters in each of the two displays. So on the display for Tab 1 have the Tab 1 related exposed filters, then on the Tab 2 display you can use your Tab 2 related exposed filters.

Comment: I actually have a similar question for Drupal 7: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94421/how-to-create-a-tabbed-view-in-a-panel-without-a-menu-entry. Can you help?