# How to create a tabbed view in a panel without a menu entry?

Tags: 7, views, panels, routes

**What is my goal?**

I'd like to create a view for my users' profile page, similar to the 'Questions' block one finds on the user pages on this website. Instead of the user's questions, I'd like to display the articles he/she created. The users should be able to reorder/filter the articles in the view by clicking on *"filter links"/tabs* similar to the ones I marked in the underneath picture.

[image: Tabbed view]

I don't know the exact term for this, but I suppose one calls this a *tabbed view*.

**What is my problem?**

I can't find any suitable solutions for this functionality on the internet, but I've read a lot of similar requests. The main problem is that the view doesn't have its own page. That means: it should just be part of the user profile page, which has been overridden with "user_view" (see: [How to create a profile page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/how-to-create-a-profile-page)) into a panels page. (This is exactly why the tabs in @Jhilke Dai's solution don't show up.)

It's also important that the path still contains the user's ID when one clicks on the tabs, because - of course - the *Articles* view needs this information, namely via the *Contextual filter: (author) User uid* > *Provide default value: User ID from URL*.

**What did I try so far?**

I've already created a view called *Articles* that displays all the articles that were added by the user. As any view would, it's displayed perfectly in the panel on my user profile pages. My next step was to add the tabs to the view. I followed @Jhilke Dai's answer to the letter, but as I mentioned before, the tabs don't show up when I don't give the Master display a normal menu entry (that's not what I want).

Comment: May be I didn't explain properly, anyways, I have updated my answer with Pictures, have a look, I hope you'll get the idea to do it for your site

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided, as defined in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mołot: I really regret that you and two other users marked this question as off-topic. In my opinion the question is a general request that only uses the comparison with Drupal Answers as a clarification. I hope that my update contains enough information about what I've already tried so far (there's no need to discuss it in detail, as everything is mentioned in Jhilke Dai's answer) and that you and the other guys will review their opinion about my question being off-topic.

Comment: The problem was in the fact that description of what you want was mainly in image - and thus unavailable for search engines. Now it's better and image really is only a clarification, so I can retract my vote.

Comment: @Jeroen, so your question now changed to Profile Page, common man, be specific while asking question. If you think your question is too big, make it 2 or 3 separate questions, so, other facing such issue will know what to do. After all, there is no limit how many questions you can ask here.

Comment: I mentioned right from the beginning that the tabbed view should be part of the user page, dear @Jhilke Dai. Perhaps you didn't read my question well enough? Anyway, I know how to do that, so it's not important. And breaking my question in pieces? I really don't know how I could do that. I think it's pretty straightforward: how can I create a tabbed view in a panel? That's about it, no?

Comment: have you checked this modules https://drupal.org/project/panels_tabs , https://drupal.org/project/panels_ajax_tab

Comment: @Bala: Thanks for your suggestion, but I prefer to use recommended releases for modules. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [QuickTabs module](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs). You create a tabbed block via QuickTabs, with each tab itself being an already defined block, page, view, etc.  Then you add the QT block to pages the same as any other.  You will probably need to create your own style for the tabs (it does come with a handful of predefined styles) to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: The QuickTabs module looked perfect, but for some reason, I always get a fatal error when I try to add a QuickTab to a panel. Any idea why? https://drupal.org/node/1910434

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but it seems like drupal is attempting to merge an array with an integer or string (maybe).  Did you try applying the ['patch' here](https://drupal.org/node/1922044)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need 3 views, just create one view with 3 pages Votes, Activity and Newest. define your fields and filters. In **Page Settings -> *Menu Option***, Use the **Menu tab**.

**Edit:** Exmaple

If **Page Path** for main view is ***mylist***

- Add Pages in View with Paths *mylist/votes*, *mylist/activity*,
  *mylist/newest* for all the 3 pages respectively
- Select **Menu Tab** and Provide the Menu for Votes, Activity and Newest respectively

---

Above was the previous reply, here is answer with some graphics.

For the demo of your use case:

- I created a taxonomy vocabulary called **DSE** with 3 terms ***Vote***, ***Activity*** and ***Newest***
- I created a new content type called **Drupal Stack Exchange**, with ***Title***, ***Questions*** and ***Tags*** field, where ***Tags*** field is *Term Reference* to **DSE**

In Views, I created a Master Display with Just Title field for demonstration, and I gave the Page path as ***questions*** like in this picture

[image]

For the Menu for Master display I selected ***Normal menu entry*** and selected **Main Menu** as its menu type:

[image]

Then I added the new Page for Activity, and in Path I gave ***questions/activity***

[image]

In Menu for Activity, I selected **Menu Tab** and gave a title called **Activity**

[image]

In Filter for Activity I selected **DSE Tag** and chosed it to be one of ***Activity Tag*** like in the picture below. (**Note**: While adding filter select only this display)

[image]

I repeated the same process for Votes and Newest, as you can see Path settings for Newest is also the Menu Tab like:

[image]

Save the view and you'll see the New Menu called ***Questions*** in **Main Menu**, and clicking the Menu will give you 3 tabbed menu inside like:

[image]

**Note**: To make tabbed menu it is required the path to be on the same Path like in above case *`questions/vote`* for Vote tab, *`questions/activity`* for Activity tab.

Finally the Sneak peak of the View page

[image]

Comment: I don't want to create new paths. If one clicks on *Votes*, *Activity* or *Newest* on a user's profile page, the path remains the same too. It's important that the path doesn't change, because my views contain information that depends on it.

Comment: Then Ajax is your best friend. Implement it however you like. Load the whole view at once and use Ajax to toggle between links in the menu..

Comment: How can I use AJAX? I always have to fill in a path when I create a new page in my view, so I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: When you create a **page** in **view** you'll see the **Page Settings** Right in the Middle. I am not sure if you understood my answer properly, I said to create **Base Path** and extend those paths for Specific Page. This way whatever information you are getting from Path will remain same. For Ajax you can use Custom JavaScript in your theme.

Comment: My main view doesn't have a path. It's just the *Master* display. When I click on the *Menu* option in the *Page settings*, there's no *Tabbed menu* option either...

Comment: I have updated my answer to highlight **Menu Tab**

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts! The tabbed pages are there now, but I still have the following problem: I don't want the 'Questions' to have a normal menu entry. I only want the 'Activity', 'Newest' and 'Votes' tabbed pages to be displayed in a panel on the users' profile page (just like on Drupal Answers). But when I put the 'DSE' view in that panel, there are no tabs anymore: I only see the 'Votes' page!

Comment: Your question and Title have changed a lot since you asked, it just isolates the whole topic what was asked before. You asked about creating **views** previously and I provided that, but I am sorry I haven't used Panels and Page Manager, as I new to Drupal too.

Comment: You are partly right. In the very beginning, I didn't explicitely say that the view shouldn't have it's own page and I forgot to mention that it's part of a panel. I thought the first thing would be clear, because I compared it with the 'Questions' on the Drupal Answers user pages. Secondly, I immediately edited my question after your first answer to tell you that I was working with a panel. I believe that all the other updates didn't change anything to the question's topic or essence: they only clarified my requests in order to let you better understand my situation.